# Could not locate file when importing it

Tags: clojure

I just started playing with clojure, and I have a question.

I create a folder called `testingclojure` in `~/` and it contains a file called `core.clj` which has a simple function like this:

```
(ns testingclojure.core)

(defn greetings 
  [{:keys [name age]}]
  (format "Hello my name is %s and I'm %s years old" name age))
```

So the filepath is: `~/testingclojure/core.clj`

Meanwhile I'm in `~/`, and I want to use it in repl, so I type:

```
(use '[testingclojure [core :as c]])
```

Unfortunately, I got an error, something like "Could not locate `testingclojure/core.clj`". How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you invoke the repl? 
Are you using leiningen or just the clojure jar?

You need to include the current folder
if you are using the clojure jar

```
java -cp [path to clojure jar];.; clojure.main
```

if you are using leiningen place your code in the src folder or use the src directive in your project.clj to point it to the right source folder.

Comment: I'm using `lein repl`

Comment: Then the filepath needs to be ~/testingclojure/src/testingclojure/core.clj and you need to make sure you have a project.clj file in the testingclojure folder